# In Python how to use Pandas to manipulate output from Prophet

Tags: python, pandas, facebook-prophet

[image]new to Python, would appreciate any help with Pandas to manipulate output from Prophet Library ( see image ).
My input Dataframe has 3 columns, Prophet only takes 2, and my output is 4 columns.
Is there also a way to loop back around and run the same for Operators 5 and 6, or do I need to add them sequntially to the code ?  Thanks in advance for your help. Gav

```
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet
df = pd.read_csv('C:\path\myfile.csv')
df.columns = ['Operator','ds','y']
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
dfprop=df[df['Operator']==1]
dfprop=dfprop[['ds','y']]
m = Prophet()
m.fit(dfprop)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=158)
forecast = m.predict(future)
forecast
forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail(158)
dfout = df.append(forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail(158))
```

[image]

Comment: post the code you have currently as well as a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant test this without a reproducible dataset but something like this should do it.

```
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet
df = pd.read_csv('C:\path')
df.columns = ['Operator','ds','y']
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])

def forecast_data(g):
    data = g[['ds','y']]
    m = Prophet()
    m.fit(data)
    future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=158)
    forecast = m.predict(future)
    forecast['Operator'] = g['Operator'].iloc[0]
    forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail(158)
    dfout = g.append(forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail(158))
    return dfout

df.groupby('Operator').apply(forecast_data)
```

apply to the group `'Operator'` and create a model for each

Comment: Awesome thank you !, will give a try, appreciate the help.

Comment: @Gavin let me know how it goes

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated

Comment: @ftthomson  it's nearly there, is there a way to pass the Operator number into the forecast dataframe as it goes ?, I tried adding forecast['Operator']=g

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't like it...   forecast.insert(loc=0,column="Operator",value=g)
    forecast[['Operator','ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail(158)
    dfout = g.append(forecast[['Operator','ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail(158))

Comment: Also tried this...   forecast.insert(loc=0,column="Operator",value=g['Operator'])

Comment: @Gavin see updated answer

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it really is appreciated, it is working perfectly now :-)

Comment: @Gavin no worries glad it helped :) if this helped feel free to accept it as the answer and upvote. Happy coding!